# Dangerous trailing space

Tags: whitespace

In [remove unwanted spaces page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_spaces) in vim wikia, it says:

> However, this is a very dangerous autocmd to have as it will always strip trailing whitespace from every file a user saves. Sometimes, trailing whitespace is desired, or even essential in a file so be careful when implementing this autocmd

Why is it so? Is there a situation where it's necessary to have trailing spaces in the end of a line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a situation where it's necessary to have trailing spaces in the end of a line?

The two most common that I encounter are:

- In the original Markdown you need to use two spaces at the end of line to signal a hard newline (in "GitHub flavoured Markdown" this does nothing, though, since this always adds a newline).
- For emails the marker for the start of a signature is `--<Space>`.

There may be other situations as well.

Comment: format=flowed for emails

Comment: Vim itself, with `inoremap foo bar     `.